# NBandroid project.properties not found

Tags: android, netbeans

I'm trying to use NBandroid plugin for developing an Android app using NetBeans. I have installed the SDK and the plugin, but whenever I try to run a project created using it. It gives me the following error..

```
\NetBeansProjects\Android\HelloWorld\build.xml:40: Source resource does not exist: \NetBeansProjects\Android\HelloWorld\project.properties
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Android SDK is updated to tools revision 14 or newer.
Look at the http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html and update your project using

```
android update project
```

command. This is needed because some files were renamed. NBAndroid plugin will be updated soon to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Open build.xml file, which is in important files dir of your project and make the below change

```
<loadproperties srcFile=”project.properties” />
```

to

```
<loadproperties srcFile=”default.properties” />
```

Comment: I got this error while trying to build using https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android
I tried the solution suggested by you but apparently the build.xml file was being generated every time I tried to build so I renamed the file default.properties to project.properties and it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this instruction carefully:
http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/Installation

Highlight this : 
**If you've installed NBAndroid Extensions you need to upload subscription key in this dialog to activate the functionality.**